# Rake db:seed NoMethodError: undefined method `sample'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed

I am trying to seed my database, but I am running into this error, and as a beginner do not know how to fix it. I'm trying to take a sample of bookmarks and assign them to some of my users. Any ideas why this is throwing an error? Here is the error:

```
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/bookmarks$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `sample' for #<Class:0xaa90cf4>
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
/home/vagrant/code/bookmarks/db/seeds.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/code/bookmarks/db/seeds.rb:46:in `times'
/home/vagrant/code/bookmarks/db/seeds.rb:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
/home/vagrant/code/bookmarks/db/seeds.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:154:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Edit:  Here is my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'faker'

# Create a User
 # user = User.new(
 #   name:     'First Last',
 #   email:    'firstlast@gmail.com',
 #   password: 'password',
 # )
 # user.skip_confirmation!
 # user.save

#Create Users
5.times do
  user = User.new(
    name:     Faker::Name.name,
    email:    Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
  )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
end
users = User.all


#Create Bookmarks
10.times do
  Bookmark.create!(
    url:    Faker::Internet.url
  )
end
bookmarks = Bookmark.all

#Create Topics
10.times do
  Topic.create!(
    name:   Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end
topics = Topic.all

users.each do |user|
  3.times do
    user.bookmarks << Bookmark.sample
  end
end

topics.each do |topic|
  3.times do
    user.topics << Topic.sample
 end
end

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{User.count} users created"
puts "#{Bookmark.count} bookmarks created"
puts "#{Topic.count} topics created"
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: At least show us your seeds.rb. What are we supposed to do without seeing your actual code?

Comment: It sounds like your seeds.rb may be trying to load random data (and doing it incorrectly). To be any more helpful than that, we'd need to see it, as @meagar said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whereever you are calling `.sample`, the object before it is apparently not the correct type of object. It should either be an array or the 'collection' which results when you query your database. Like this...

`posts = Post.all`

`posts.sample` would work correctly

any object which is not an array (or like an array) will not have the 'sample' method available for you to use

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `sample` on a class as that is not a valid method. The `sample` method is used for arrays or ActiveRecord::Relation arrays.

For example, each of these would return a random

`[0,1,2,3].sample`

`(0..10).to_a.sample`

`Post.all.sample`

However, something like these examples would give an error.

`User.sample`

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'sample' for  #<Class:0x00000007faa378>`

`(9..199).sample`

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'sample' for 9..199:Range`